# How to use Angular-UI bootstrap in JsFiddle?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, jsfiddle

Maybe a real newbie question, but anyway.

I'm working on a Angular script which I'm testing in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nagilo/a4wx3pcq/). Therefore the framework is set to Angular JS 1.2.1 (the highest one available there). Within the script I want to use Angular-UI bootstrap for typeahead and other features.

When I add the dependency to my module declaration I get an error.

```
angular.module('MyModule', ['ui.bootstrap'])
```

> Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available!

Question: On the left side I can add references to external libraries but I'm kinda too stupid to find the URI that is used to reference Angular-UI. Any idea?

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js could help.

Comment: Or here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js

Comment: Both are working. Thanks!